# What Language is Html Written in?

Tags: html

What type of Language is Html Based on? . I Already learned html , Css , Php , Js , And Ruby
But I Always wondered what Language Html Is Written in.I don't think it's Written in something Like C.

Comment: You probably wanted to ask what language a software like internet explorer is written to parse and understand html.

Comment: Well, the question in the body - *what type of language is HTML based on* - is a real and answerable question. Quentin's answered it below. Though it may not be what the OP meant.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not "written" in anything. It's a **markup language**. HTML is parsed by the browser which renders the webpage to display.

It isn't a programming language. But maybe if it helps, you could think of HTML as a interpreted language and the browser as an interpreter.

Answer (score 10):

If you're talking about how it is implemented by a browser, it is usually written in an object-oriented language due to its modular nature.

Firefox - which uses C++ - has an open source policy, you can view the code for the html parser [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/parser/).

Answer (score 5):

- HTML 2/3.2/4.x are SGML Applications
- The various versions of XHTML are XML Applications
- HTML 5 is not defined in terms of another language

Comment: How does HTML 5 fall outside of SGML?

Comment: @JoAreBy — By having its parsing rules defined by its own specification and not in terms of SGML.

Comment: What you're saying might just be that SGML is adopted by the HTML 5 standard. Can you give an example where HTML 5 does not comply with SGML? Or am I missing your point completely?

Comment: No. I don't know SGML well enough. Things that might cause it to not qualify are the weird Doctype, the lack of DTD, allowing `true` as a value for boolean attributes, and the use of the `/>` syntactic sugar for the XML addicted. But the point is that, even if the syntax it uses is compliant with SGML, it isn't expressed as an SGML application.

Comment: Interesting. I thought SGML was a really simple standard that covered pretty much everything that "looks like" HTML, XML, VRML, basically anything *ML... I'll have to look into it i guess.

Comment: At 155 pages, simple it is not. You can get it from http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=16387 though.

Answer (score 4):

##### Browsers have an engine that interprets and renders HTML on the devices view port.

---

Below is a somewhat detailed resource that explains to it's readers how HTML rendering in the browser works:

###### [How the Browser works: Tree Rendering Construction](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Render_tree_construction)